# Why does Dynamics AX Client stop working, after deploying a Service Group?

Tags: web-services, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

I know this is not a coding issue, but this is part of the development in AX.

> THE PROBLEM > After deploying a Service Group in the Client, AX crashes and I get this error:
>
> Microsoft Dynamics AX has stopped working

and then

> Microsoft Dynamics AX is restarting

This happens every time when I try to deploy a Service Group.

I'm developing in MS Dynamics AX 2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First try an incremental CIL update, if this does not solve it, try a full CIL update.

Also check the Windows application log for any details of the error.